# Adding localStorage items in the order it was added

Tags: javascript, sorting, for-loop, local-storage

I want to sort localStorage items by the order it was added. The code works just fine, where i am able to add items to the localStorage array and loop through the array as HTML code.

If I add the 3rd item to my array, it will become the 2nd item on the list. I don't understand why the items have a completely random order?

Here is my code down below.

```
<body>

        <h2>Local Storage - JavaScript</h2>

        <form method="post" action="index.html" id="form">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Insert Data</legend>
                <input id="enterKey" type="text" placeholder="Enter Key...">
                <input id="enterValue" type="text" placeholder="Enter Value...">
                <input type="submit" value="Set Reminder">
            </fieldset>
        </form>

        <ul id="output">
        </ul>

    </body>

    <script>
        form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {

            const key = enterKey.value;
            const value = enterValue.value;

            if (key && value) {
                localStorage.setItem(key, value);
            }

        })

        for (let i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {

            const key = localStorage.key(i);
            const value = localStorage.getItem(key);

            var li = document.createElement("li");
            li.textContent = `${key}: ${value}</li>`;
            output.appendChild(li);

        }
   </script>
```

Answer (score 4):

The order is random because localStorage is stored as key-value pairs, and such objects do not guarantee ordering. In fact some languages deliberately randomise the ordering so that programmers won't rely on the items being in any particular order. So if you want to have ordering, you will need to introduce the ordering key into the data itself, and then read all the items and sort on the key after that.

Something like:

```
form.addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
  const key = enterKey.value;
  const value = enterValue.value;
  if (key && value) {
    const count = localStorage.length;
    const val = {
      value,
      order: count,
    }
    localStorage.setItem(key, val);
  }

})

const items = [];
for (let i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
  const key = localStorage.key(i);
  const value = localStorage.getItem(key);
  items.push({key, value});
}
items.sort((a, b) => a.value.order - b.value.order).forEach(item => {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  li.textContent = `${item.key}: ${item.value.value}</li>`;
  output.appendChild(li);
});
```

Comment: Or instead of an ordering key, just date-stamp it instead and then order on that.

Comment: Yes, probably better.